# Directing all AJAX requests to https

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, https

I have included the following in my .htaccess file so that all page requests are redirected to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}:443%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Now if I make an AJAX call using a relative address without specifying the full address, will the AJAX request get redirected to https as well, when https is not specified? As the address is not shown in the address bar of the browser, I have no way to check whether http or https is used.

Answer (score 0):

As far I remember the value of `%{HTTPS}` can only be `on` if it is not aviable the key simply won't exists. If you don't post data the AJAX request will follow normal redirects however redirecting the AJAX request to https will cause a cross site request (that includes different protocols and subdomains) which is normally forbidden. There is a techique called [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) that allows such things. For implementing that you need to output the folowing http header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
```

There you need to exchange the domain with your actual one. Than you can also directly query the HTTPS resource without redirecting.

If you have installed [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) you can use this line in your .htaccess file:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com"
```